# Retain variable defined before "| yad --progress"

Tags: bash, shell, yad

I'd like to define a variable within a process that is piped to a yad progress bar while retaining it outside of that process. e.g:

```
(a=3 ; sleep 1) | yad --progress --auto-close
echo $a
```

I'd also like to avoid [writing that variable to a temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809236/yad-multi-progress-bar-with-background-processes-bash) to retrieve later, especially considering it may sometimes be an array, associative array or whatever messy multiline string that would require more code to reconstruct from a file.

I think I should be able to use redirection rather than a pipe but I don't know how exactly in this situation and all my attemps have failed.

Comment: is `export` what you're looking for?

Comment: @LinFelix no, `export` will not help. `export a` would make the value of `a` available in a subshell, it won't make any changes that subshell makes to `a` also be present in the parent shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this, using `{ }` for *grouping* commands and `>( )` for *process substitution*:

```
{ a=3; sleep 1; } > >(yad --progress --auto-close)
echo "$a"
```

- you declare the variable in a *subshell*: `( )`, the variable don't exists for the parent shell.
- if you use a pipe: `|`, the command still be in a *subshell*, that's why the need for `> >( )` process substitution.

---

Process Substitution `>(command ...)` or `<(...)` is replaced by a temporary filename. Writing or reading that file causes bytes to get piped to the command inside. Often used in combination with file redirection: `cmd1 2> >(cmd2)`.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024